# implementing in CUDA a large boolean sparse matrix (having possibly 10 million entries) for RDF triples

Tags: matrix, cuda

I am looking for a suitable matrix format to represent a very large boolean sparse matrix (containing only 0's and 1's) in CUDA. I have been reading the [CUSPARSE documentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/cusparse) and found several formats such as Compressed Sparse Row (CSR), Compressed Sparse Column (CSC), etc. Since the matrix non-zero elements are all 1, which particular format should be the perfect choice? The operations in matrix are basically writes that convert 0 to 1 based on some condition. The main aim is to query the matrix for the (row,col) pair for each 1's in a particular row. Any insight into matrix formats and efficiency of search row-wise shall be welcome.

@Robert Crovella: Many thanks for clarifying the issue. I understand CUDA does not has much role to play unless and until we decide to search for 1's (non-zero values) on different rows simultaneously, of course no writes on the matrix. This may be done as described by you for the search of all 1's in the second row (==1). Each thread can then search for a separate row asynchronously for non-zero values (in our case 1's). Just need to mention and would like to take your view on whether we can drop the values vector as it contains all ones. We will save on the space complexity a bit(though it will not be a major factor in terms of space). The space requirements will be nnz+n+1 instead of 2nnz+n+1.

Comment: Prior art is great, but is there are actually a need to go all-out smart on this problem? 10 million bits is just slightly more than a megabyte. That's not actually that large, and many operations can be vectorized to process 32 or 128 entries (bits) at once.

Comment: One at least has to *consider* the possibility that "10 million entries" (confusingly) referred to the number of rows/columns of the matrix. Is this the case?

Comment: I understand that total size of the matrix in terms of bytes will not be very large. I was keen to know of a suitable search operation for finding the relevant columns among millions across a given row that have the value 1. One thing that comes to my mind is the masking option. In this context, do I need to go for a particular preferred sparse matrix representation scheme or any thing will suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As near as I can tell your question has nothing to do with CUDA.  You just need a tutorial on sparse matrix compressed storage formats.  I'll suggest you google for that (here's [one example](http://netlib.org/linalg/html_templates/node90.html), but I will attempt to answer this question:

> I was keen to know of a suitable search operation for finding the relevant columns among millions across a given row that have the value 1.

or:

> (how) to query the matrix for the (row,col) pair for each 1's in a particular row.

If you have a matrix in CSR format, you will have a sequence of row pointers, and a set of column indices for each (non-zero) element.  Suppose I have the following "sparse" matrix:

```
0   1   0
1   0   1 
0   1   0
```

The CSR representation would be:

```
index:           0    1    2    3     
values:          1    1    1    1
column indices:  1    0    2    1
row pointers:    0    1    3    4
```

If I have therefore a CSR representation, and I want to answer the question "Which columns for the second row have non-zero entries" it's a simple matter of starting with the row pointer for the second row (== 1), proceeding to the last element *before* the next row pointer (3), and reading off the respective column indices.  In this case there are two column indices: 0 and 2.  Therefore, row 1 has two non-zero elements, in columns 0 and 2.

Programmatically, if I wanted to increment each non-zero element in row 2 in CUDA code, I could:

```
int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
if (idx < rowPtr[2] - rowPtr[1]) 
  values[idx + rowPtr[1]]++;
```

[CUSPARSE](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html) and [CUSP](https://github.com/cusplibrary/cusplibrary/wiki/Quick-Start-Guide) provide many useful sparse matrix manipulation functions.