# Converting a dense matrix to sparse CSR format with cuSPARSE

Tags: cuda

I want to use `Scsrmv` cusparse function.

Reading the documentation from [here](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#axzz33TAVudf5), I can't figure how to define `csrRowPtrA` and `csrColIndA`:

> csrRowPtrA :  integer array of m+1 elements that contains the start of
>   every row and the end of the last row plus one.
>
> csrColIndA :  integer array of nnz ( = csrRowPtrA(m) - csrRowPtrA(0) )
>   column indices of the nonzero elements of matrix A.

So , for example:

```
  float *devRow;
  cudaMalloc((void **)&devRow, (m+1)*sizeof(float));
```

and if `A` is the matrix, then:

```
for (int i=0; i<m; i+= n)   //m is rows , n is columns
    devRow[i] = A[i];
```

This is for the start of every row. For the last row and plus `1`? This confused me.

And for columns? Something like:

```
for (int i=0;i<nnz;i++)
   devCol = devRow[m] - devRow[0];
```

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" There are many resources available to understand how to assemble a CSR sparse matrix.  There are [cusparse docs](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#compressed-sparse-row-format-csr) as well as many web resources.  There are also [sample codes](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-samples/index.html#conjugategradient) showing assembly of a CSR matrix, and [answers here on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22281973/implementing-in-cuda-a-large-boolean-sparse-matrix-having-possibly-10-million-e).

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, but if I already have a matrix which I know it is sparse , how can I handle it?Because the examples create a matrix like that.And what about if I don't know how many non zero elements it has?

Comment: You would convert the "dense" matrix to the sparse format of your choice (e.g. CSR).  The cusparse link I provided gives an example of CSR sparse representation of a dense matrix (all 3 required vectors) and so does the answer I linked.

Comment: @Robert Crovella:OK, I can see how one can move from a dense matrix to sparse format.But how can I do this in code?Is there a routine which computes csrRowPtrA etc..?Thank you

Comment: Please read the cusparse documentation.  Use [dense2csr](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-dense2csr).

Comment: @Robert Crovella:Ok, I missed that!That's what I was looking for.Thank you..If you want make it an asnwer please.Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert a dense matrix to sparse with code you write yourself.  For the CSR (compressed-sparse-row) formulation, you could also use the CUSPARSE [function](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-lt-t-gt-dense2csr) for this.

The general format of a CSR sparse matrix representation is documented in many places, including the CUSPARSE [manual](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#compressed-sparse-row-format-csr).

Answer (score 3):

Following Robert Crovella's answer, this is a fully worked example on how converting a sparse matrix stored in *dense* format into a *CSR (compressed row storage)* format. I hope it will be useful to other users.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cusparse_v2.h>

#include "Utilities.cuh"

/***************************/
/* CUSPARSE ERROR CHECKING */
/***************************/
static const char *_cusparseGetErrorEnum(cusparseStatus_t error)
{
    switch (error)
    {

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ALLOC_FAILED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INVALID_VALUE";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ARCH_MISMATCH";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MAPPING_ERROR";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_EXECUTION_FAILED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_INTERNAL_ERROR";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_MATRIX_TYPE_NOT_SUPPORTED";

        case CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT:
            return "CUSPARSE_STATUS_ZERO_PIVOT";
    }

    return "<unknown>";
}

inline void __cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err, const char *file, const int line)
{
    if(CUSPARSE_STATUS_SUCCESS != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "CUSPARSE error in file '%s', line %Ndims\Nobjs %s\nerror %Ndims: %s\nterminating!\Nobjs",__FILE__, __LINE__,err, \
                                _cusparseGetErrorEnum(err)); \
        cudaDeviceReset(); assert(0); \
    }
}

extern "C" void cusparseSafeCall(cusparseStatus_t err) { __cusparseSafeCall(err, __FILE__, __LINE__); }

/********/
/* MAIN */
/********/
int main()
{
    // --- Initialize cuSPARSE
    cusparseHandle_t handle;    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreate(&handle));

    const int Nrows = 4;                        // --- Number of rows
    const int Ncols = 5;                        // --- Number of columns

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A_dense = (double*)malloc(Nrows*Ncols*sizeof(*h_A_dense));

    // --- Column-major ordering
    h_A_dense[0] = 1.0f; h_A_dense[4] = 4.0f; h_A_dense[8]  = 0.0f; h_A_dense[12] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[16] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[1] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[5] = 2.0f; h_A_dense[9]  = 3.0f; h_A_dense[13] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[17] = 0.0f;
    h_A_dense[2] = 5.0f; h_A_dense[6] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[10] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[14] = 7.0f; h_A_dense[18] = 8.0f;
    h_A_dense[3] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[7] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[11] = 9.0f; h_A_dense[15] = 0.0f; h_A_dense[19] = 6.0f;

    //create device array and copy host to it
    double *d_A_dense;  gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A_dense, h_A_dense, Nrows * Ncols * sizeof(*d_A_dense), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    // --- Descriptor for sparse matrix A
    cusparseMatDescr_t descrA;      cusparseSafeCall(cusparseCreateMatDescr(&descrA));
    cusparseSetMatType      (descrA, CUSPARSE_MATRIX_TYPE_GENERAL);
    cusparseSetMatIndexBase (descrA, CUSPARSE_INDEX_BASE_ZERO);  

    int nnz = 0;                                // --- Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix
    const int lda = Nrows;                      // --- Leading dimension of dense matrix
    // --- Device side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *d_nnzPerVector;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*d_nnzPerVector)));
    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDnnz(handle, CUSPARSE_DIRECTION_ROW, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, &nnz));
    // --- Host side number of nonzero elements per row
    int *h_nnzPerVector = (int *)malloc(Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_nnzPerVector, d_nnzPerVector, Nrows * sizeof(*h_nnzPerVector), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    printf("Number of nonzero elements in dense matrix = %i\n\n", nnz);
    for (int i = 0; i < Nrows; ++i) printf("Number of nonzero elements in row %i = %i \n", i, h_nnzPerVector[i]);
    printf("\n");

    // --- Device side dense matrix
    double *d_A;            gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, nnz * sizeof(*d_A)));
    int *d_A_RowIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*d_A_RowIndices)));
    int *d_A_ColIndices;    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*d_A_ColIndices)));

    cusparseSafeCall(cusparseDdense2csr(handle, Nrows, Ncols, descrA, d_A_dense, lda, d_nnzPerVector, d_A, d_A_RowIndices, d_A_ColIndices));

    // --- Host side dense matrix
    double *h_A = (double *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A));     
    int *h_A_RowIndices = (int *)malloc((Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices));
    int *h_A_ColIndices = (int *)malloc(nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, nnz*sizeof(*h_A), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_RowIndices, d_A_RowIndices, (Nrows + 1) * sizeof(*h_A_RowIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_A_ColIndices, d_A_ColIndices, nnz * sizeof(*h_A_ColIndices), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("A[%i] = %.0f ", i, h_A[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < (Nrows + 1); ++i) printf("h_A_RowIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_RowIndices[i]); printf("\n");

    for (int i = 0; i < nnz; ++i) printf("h_A_ColIndices[%i] = %i \n", i, h_A_ColIndices[i]);   

}
```

Comment: Thanks @Vitality, really useful example. The current [documentation (v11.6.0)](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#dense2csr) says ` [[DEPRECATED]] use cusparseDense2Sparse() instead. The routine will be removed in the next major release`. So [cusparseDenseToSparse()](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cusparse/index.html#cusparse-generic-function-dense2sparse) would be the way to go now. [Example](https://github.com/NVIDIA/CUDALibrarySamples/blob/master/cuSPARSE/dense2sparse_csr/dense2sparse_csr_example.c)